# Sending users a password insertion Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am using Django Rest Framework and want to be able to send a user a password reset view. It actually comes from a user inviting them into the software but it automatically sets a secure password.

I want to be able to send that user an email asking them to change their password.

How can I go about this?

Answer (score 0):

you need to use builtin apps in django for password reset you need to use it on ur urls.py

for example:

in settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
     ...
    'password_reset',
     ...

]
```

urls.py in project:

```
path('',include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
```

in app urls.py:

```
path('password_reset/', include('password_reset.urls')),
```